# tocloft package adds page number to first side of table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, tocloft

I have a problem with the `tocloft` package. Whenever I try to include it in my document, the first page (only) of the table of contents contains a page number, even so I don´t want any page numbers at all for the toc. When I remove the `\usepackage{tocloft}` call, the toc is displayed without a page number, so somehow it must be messing up the layout...

Is there a way to tell `tocloft` to not adjust anything in the table of contents?

`\pagestyle{empty}` and `\thispagestyle{empty}`

don´t solve the problem.

Note: I am using the `tocloft` package only so I can create a list of equations (via `\newlistof` command from `tocloft`). So I would also be glad about way to get the `\newlistof` command without the `tocloft` package.

EDIT: Example:

Thank you for considering my problem: Here is a code example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
...
//the part responsible for creating creating the listofequations
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{} 
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname} 
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{% 
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\hfill} 
...
//sample equation
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Eq1}
a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}
\end{equation}
\myequations{Satz des Pythagoras \ref{eq:Eq1}}
...
//displaying the list of equations
\subsection{Equations}
\renewcommand{\listequationsname}{}
\listofmyequations
```

Thanks in advance!

### SOLUTION:

The command posted by Andrew Swann as a comment solved the issue for me. 
I only had to add `\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}}` before `\tableofcontents`

Thank you alot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please show us a complete and small example which shows your problem. Include only the documentclass, the needed package, the toc and one list of equations.

Comment: The manual suggests `\renewcommand{\cftafterZtitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}}` where `Z` is the list type.

Comment: thx @Andrew Swann: adding \renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}} before \tableofcontents solved the issue!

Comment: @Philipp: And if you answer your question yourself, you **might** obtain the `selflearner` badge too ;-)

Comment: @Christian: yeaaa :D

Comment: @AndrewSwann Want to make that an answer and get it off the unanswered list? Thanks.

Comment: @Johannes_B Done.

Answer (score 2):

The manual suggests `\renewcommand{\cftafterZtitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}}` where `Z` is the list type.  In your case `Z` is `equ` so you should add

```
\renewcommand{\cftafterequtitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

to your preamble.

By the way, your command `\myequations` should end with `\ignorespaces` instead of `\hfill` so that following text doesn't necessarily start a new paragraph.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

% the part responsible for creating creating the listofequations
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{} 
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname} 
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{% 
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\ignorespaces} 
\renewcommand{\cftafterequtitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}} 

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

If the sides of a right-angle triangle in the Euclidean plane have
lengths \( a \), \( b \), \( c \) with \( c \) the length of the
hypotenuse, then they are related by
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:Pyth}
  a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2}.
\end{equation}
\myequations{Pythagoras' Theorem} Note that this equation has integer
solutions such as \( (a,b,c) = (3,4,5) \).  This should be contrasted
with Fermat's equation
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:Fermat}
  a^{n} + b^{n} = c^{n},\quad\text{for \( n\geqslant 3 \).}
\end{equation}
\myequations{Fermat's equation}

%displaying the list of equations
\clearpage
\subsection{Equations}
\listofmyequations 

\end{document}
```